# Javascript wrong target.ids' return

Tags: javascript, html

I won't post all my code because it's quite big. But i have a problem in a part of it. I cannot get tds' id (i mean cells' id in table). What's wrong with it? Thanks.

```
function controllerDrawTable()  //creating table
{
    var table = document.getElementById("tablefield");

    for (var i = 0; i < model.fieldSquare; i++)
    {
        var row = table.insertRow(i);
        for (var j = 0; j < model.fieldSquare; j++)
        {
            var cell = row.insertCell(j);
            var atr = letter[i] + number[j]; //it's just a values for creating IDs like A3, B5, etc.
            cell.setAttribute("id", atr);
            cell.onclick = controller.fire; //here i handle clicks on the table.
        }
    }
}
```

And here is my function which handle clicks on the table:

```
function controllerFire(event)        
{
    var cell = document.getElementById(event.target.id);
    console.log(cell); //i get <td id="C0"> instead of "C0"
}
```

Comment: You get the whole element with `getElementById`. Just get the Id from it. You used `setAttribute` there should also be a `get`on it

Comment: `document.getElementById` give you dom element, not id, use `cell.getAttribute('id')` to get its id

Comment: Or just `console.log(event.target.id);`, as you used it right above it.

Comment: event.target.id it self giving ID of the clicked cell, what else you want... :D

Comment: Thanks you all for help! I'm blind a bit :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You read the element from the id itself.

You should get expected value in in event.target.id it self. Check its value.

```
 console.log(event.target.id);
```